# Best way to store string of known maximum length in file for fast load into vector<string> in C++

Tags: c++, string, file-io, vector

I've got big amount of text data which I need to save to file for next reprocessing. These data are stored in table like vector< vector< string > > - every record (vector) has same number of attributes(vector). So, going through the vector I can find the max length of every attribute in table and count of records. Now I have to write these data to file (can be binary) in that way that I will be able to load them back into vector< vector< string > > very fast. It doesn't matter how much time will writing take but I need reading to vector implement in the fastest way.

Due to fact that data will be processed "record by record" the whole file may not will be load to memory. But for fast reading I want to use buffer 256 MB or 512 MB.

So for now I implemented this in this way:

1. Data are stored in two files - description file and data file. Description file contains the count of records, count of attributes and maximum length of every attribute. Data file is binary file of chars. There are no values or records separators, just values. Every value in concrete attribute has same length so if some value has smaller length than maximum length, the remaining chars are null characters '\0'.
2. Then I read chunk of file to char array buffer (256 MB or 512 MB) with std::fread. When application calls function vector getNext(), I read the chunk of chars from buffer (because I know length of every attribute) and append every char to concrete string to create vector.

But, this way seems not so fast for my purpose when I need parse big count of records in loop from buffer to vector. Is another better way to do whole this problem?

This part of code is parsing chars from buffer to values:

```
string value;
vector<string> record;
int pos = bfrIndex(); // returns current position in buffer. position of values of next record
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < d.colSize.size(); i++) { // d.colSize is vector of every attribute
    value.clear();
    value.reserve(d.colSize[i]);
    for(unsigned int j = pos; j < pos + d.colSize[i]; j++) {
        if (buffer[j] == '\0') break;
        value += buffer[j];
    }
    record.push_back(value);
    pos += d.colSize[i]; // set position in buffer to next value
}
return record;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider a binary approach that used the method employed in Doom's .wad files. I.e a directory with length & file offsets of each resource, followed by the resources themselves. With a small amount of overhead for the directory, you get instant knowledge of both where to find each string and how long they each are.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<vector<string> >` is a 3d character "cube" where every dimension vary in size along the others. Unless you are able to predict each "size", you risk to read one-by one and reallocate every time.

Fast reading happens when you can "load up" the data all in once, and than define how to split. The data structure will probably be a single string, and a `vector<vector<range> >` where range is a `std::pair<std::string::const_iterator>`.

The problem -here- is that you cannot manipulate the strings being them tightened together.

A second chance is maintain the dynamic nature of `vector<vector<string> >`,but store the dataso that each "size" can be read before the data tehnselves, so that you can resize the vectos and then read the content into its componets.

In pseudocode:

```
template<class Stream, class Container>
void save(const Container& c, const stream& s)
{ s.write(c.size()); for(auto& e: c) save(e,s) }

template<class Stream, class Container>
void load(Container& c, const stream& s)
{ 
   int sz=0; s.read(c.size()); c.resize(sz);
   for(auto& i:c) load(i,s);
}
```

Of course, specialized for string-s so that saving/loading a string actually writes/reads its own chars.